# why the last new-line-character not replaced

Tags: awk

the file to be processed by awk.

```
hello world
hello Jack
hello Jim

Hello Marry
Hello Bob
Hello Everyone
```

And my command is `awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS="\n";} {gsub("\n","@"); print}'`. The awk manual said that when the RS is set to the null (empty?) string, then records are separated by blank lines. So the result is expected to be

```
hello world@hello Jack@hello Jim@
hello Marry@hello Bob@hello Everyone@
```

But actually, the result is

```
hello world@hello Jack@hello Jim
hello Marry@hello Bob@hello Everyone
```

The last new-line-character is not replaced by `@`. Is it because the last new-line-character of a record is ommited by awk when awk read and cut content to fields? Are there some manuals about the details of how awk read and cut and process fields with patterns and actions? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't have trailing `@` in output is:

- if you set `RS=""`, it is similar with `RS="\n\n+"` (*but with difference, I explain it later). So the longest (>=2) continuous line-breaks would be used by awk as `RS`.
- looking at your data, after the `Jim` there are two `\n`s, until the next text block. So awk will take the two `\n` as RS, so there is **no** ending `\n` in your record (Jim record). of course, your `gsub` won't replace it. You see the line break in your output, it was brought by `print`
- the 2nd line in your output has no ending `@` either, because we used `RS=""` instead of `RS="\n\n+"`. The important difference is, for `RS=""`, leading newlines in the input data file are ignored, and if a file ends without extra blank lines after the last record, the final newline is removed from the record. That's why there is no trailing `@` in output line#2.

If you changed it into `RS="\n\n+"`, you should see the ending `@` on the 2nd line in your output.

I guess you want to find out why the output you got was not something you expected. but not try to achieve your expected output, right? if your question is how to get that output, I would edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, I just want to find out the reason. I have tried `RS="\n\n+"`. But the result depends on the version of awk. In `3.1.3`, no `@` at the end. But in `3.1.7`, `@` exists.

Comment: @Donglei I tested with `GNU Awk 4.1.0`, with `\n\n+`, there was a `@` at the end. (with your example input)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at this page: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Multiple-Line

It says:
*"When RS is set to the empty string, and FS is set to a single character, the newline character always acts as a field separator."*

So you do not have to specify `FS=\n`, it happens automatically if you say `RS=""`..

In order to produce your expected output you can do the following:

```
BEGIN{
    RS=""
} 
{
    $0=$0 ORS
    gsub("\n","@")
    print
}
```

Comment: if the operation is done just on `$0`, with or without `FS` makes no difference. it is not the point. and with `FS='\n'`, will ignore white spaces as `FS`, which is useful, depends on the requirement.

Comment: @Kent Thanks for the comment, but I am not sure I understand your point :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland That link is helpful. But after I read it, I doubt I have involved in a problem whose answer depends on versions and POSIX and GNU extensions.